# different usages of the verb AGREE

Tags: prepositions, word-order

> 1. The terms which were **agreed** upon yesterday.
> 2. The terms upon which **agreed** yesterday.
> 3. Upon the terms which **agreed** yesterday.

Could you tell me which of them is more acceptable and natural?

And, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 2):

Your first example sounds the most natural.

I think the reason is because just `agreed` is a verb in the active voice, and `were agreed upon` works like a verb in the passive voice(that means that the verb "happened to" the noun").

It makes sense for terms to be agreed upon, but it does not make sense for terms to do the "agreeing" themselves.

You do not have a noun in your second 2 examples that would do "agreeing"

Comment: Specifically, "terms" can "agree" with each other if they are consistent (like in a mathematical expression) -- but this usage of "agree" does **not** mean "sentient beings negotiated a deal."